# css sub menu links displaying under text below the menu

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS Menu with sub menu links but if there is text below the menu, the sub menu displays under the text and i cannot hover over the links

here is the CSS:

```
.vertical-nav {
    height:auto;
    list-style:none;
    width: 100%; /******* MODIFIED ********/
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.vertical-nav li {
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background-color: #666;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;  /******* MODIFIED ********/
}
.vertical-nav li:hover {
    background-color:#f36f25;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.vertical-nav li a {
    font-family:Calibri, Arial;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.vertical-nav li.current {
    background-color:#F36F25;
}
.vertical-nav li.current a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul {
    display:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:125px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-left:-5px;
}
vertical-nav ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
vertical-nav ul li:hover ul li {
    background-color:#555555;
    width:125px;
    height:30px;
    display:inline-block;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li:hover {
    background-color:#333333;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li a {
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.vertical-nav li ul {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
.vertical-nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
.vertical-nav li:hover .sub-menu
{
    display: table;
}
.sub-menu li
{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 180px;
    white-space: nowrap;  
    display:table-row;
}
.sub-menu li a
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

and a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7z2sE/

how can i make the sub menu links display over any text that is below...

Comment: There's something funky about those selectors. `vertical-nav ul li ul li a` doesn't target anything. Neither does any of the ones with `vertical-nav` and more than one `ul`

Comment: Also, having both `.vertical-nav li:hover ul` and `.vertical-nav li:hover .sub-menu` is another possible poor design choice, since they target the same element, with the latter being more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7z2sE/1/
add `position:relative;z-index:1;` to .sub-menu li

Answer (score 0):

To do what you are after use absolute positioning and give the text a z-index that is higher than the element behind it.